# Remove empty space from file uploads?

Tags: html, image, file, upload

So I have this HTML file upload form with the backend as below:

```
if(isset($_POST['two'])){
    $target_dir = "pageimg/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 0;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } else {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    }

// Check if file already exists

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $uploadOk = 2;
}
// Check file size

if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000) {
    $uploadOk = 3;
}
// Allow certain file formats

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 4;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error

if ($uploadOk == 5) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

// if everything is ok, try to upload file

} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
}
```

This works and uploads files as it should, however, if I upload a file such as FB Logo.png it will upload as such with the space. I am looking to edit this script to close any spaces or rename the images? I have looked around and have found no luck on how to implement any script into this current script? It all seems a bit like "here is the code" work it out yourself and I've had no luck. I did try this...

```
str_replace(" ", "_", $_FILES['image']['name']);
```

but not too sure I have added it correctly? The image failed to upload on test.

Also, how would I then recall the image name? Would I use :

```
$_FILES['name'];
```

just to recall the image name?

Comment: Your destination filename is in $target_file. If you want to remove spaces you can use str_replace on that variable.